# How to test with spec with factory_girl in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, specifications

I try to run my spec with factory_girl. My app/models/student_spec.rb as follows..,
require 'spec_helper'

```
describe Student do
   it "should work" do
     Factory.create(:name => 'User2', :age => '22', :department => 'IT')
   end
end
```

But it throws an error as

```
Failures:

  1) Student should work
     Failure/Error: Factory.create(:name => 'User2', :age => '22', :department =
> 'IT')
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `to_sym' for {:name=>"User2", :age=>"22", :department=>"
IT"}:Hash
     # ./spec/models/student_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'


Finished in 0.00073 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

spec/factories.rb as given
require 'factory_girl'

```
Factory.define :student do |s|
    s.name 'user2'
    s.age '22'
    s.department 'IT'
end
```

I'm trying to access the record from database using spec.Either to create/update or find the record from database.But it doesn't work for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the name of the factory.

`Factory.create(:student, :name => 'User2', :age => '22', :department => 'IT')`

Although it doesn't look like you're overriding your factory defaults except for capitalizing 'user2'.

You can just use `Factory(:student)`.